# Evento que oculte dos tablas con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas tardes tengo un código que me funciona bien y lo que hace es que al darle en habitacion 1 +habitacion me muestra habitacion 2 y en habitacion 2 al darle +habitacion me muestra habitacion 3 en cada uno puedo ocultar pero quisiera que en habitacion 1 pudiera darle ocultar y me oculte simultaneamente habitacion 2 y habitacion 3 porque al darle en estos momentos a ocultar en habitacion 1 cuando esta abierto habitacion 2 y habitacion 3 me queda abierto habitacion 3 y quisiera que solo quedara habitacion 1 osea me vuelva al estado inicial. A continuación el código gracias.

```js
function desplegar(tabla_a_desplegar, estadoT, estadoTfila) {
  console.log(estadoT)
  var tablA = document.getElementById(tabla_a_desplegar);
  var estadOt = document.getElementById(estadoT);
  var fila = document.getElementById(estadoTfila);

  switch (tablA.style.display) {
    case "none":
      tablA.style.display = "block";
      estadOt.innerHTML = "Ocultar";
      fila.innerHTML = "";
      fila.innerHTML = " La fila de id: " + fila.id + ". Contiene: " + fila.innerHTML + " :: " + fila.style.background;
      break;
    default:
      tablA.style.display = "none";
      estadOt.innerHTML = "+Habitacion"
      break;
  }


}
```

```html
<table style="margin-left:27px; margin-right:27px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">Habitacion 1</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">Adulto</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left;margin-top:12px">&nbsp;Ni&ntilde;o</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">
          <a class="registro registrolinea habitacion" id="estadoT" onClick="desplegar('tabla_a_desplegar','estadoT', 'estadoTfila')" style="background: #AEE756; cursor: pointer;">+ Habitacion</a>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">
          <select class="form-control seleccionunoir" id="sel1">

            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>



          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left;margin-top:12px">
          <select class="form-control selecciondosir" id="sel1">

            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>



          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="tabla_a_desplegar" style="margin-left:26px; margin-right:27px; margin-top:-15px; display:none; ">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">Habitacion 2</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px; margin-left:-09px">Adulto</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left;margin-top:12px">&nbsp;Ni&ntilde;o</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">
          <a class="registro registrolinea habitacion" id="estadoT2" onClick="desplegar('tabla_b_desplegar','estadoT2', 'estadoTfila')" style="background: #AEE756; cursor: pointer;">+ Habitacion</a>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px; margin-left:-09px">
          <select class="form-control seleccionunoir" id="sel1">

            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>



          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left;margin-top:12px">
          <select class="form-control selecciondosir" id="sel1">

            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>



          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<table id="tabla_b_desplegar" style="margin-left:26px; margin-right:27px; margin-top:-15px; display:none; ">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">Habitacion 3</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px; margin-left:-09px">Adulto</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left;margin-top:12px">&nbsp;Ni&ntilde;o</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>



      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px;">
          <select class="form-control seleccionunoir" id="sel1">

            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>



          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left;margin-top:12px; ">
          <select class="form-control selecciondosir" id="sel1">

            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>



          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="margin-left:180px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button style="margin: 0 auto" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Buscar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias Wilfredo fue de excelente ayuda y lo vi  ahora de una manera diferente muchas gracias por el apoyo y cada dia poder aprender mas de este gran lenguaje

Answer (score 2):

Como pasas valores diferentes a la función `desplegar`, una solución rápida sería comprobar qué valor se ha pasado y si es el primero, ocultar las dos filas siguientes en lugar de sólo la primera. La idea es que si la segunda tabla es la que se oculta, comprobar si la tercera está visible y esconderla si lo está.

Podrías hacer esa comprobación en `desplegar` cuando se oculte una tabla (nota que este código es específico para el problema que presentas, si cambias el código, por ejemplo añadiendo más tablas, tendrás que buscar una solución más genérica):

```
// si la tabla que se oculta es la segunda y la tercera tabla está visible
if (tablA.id == "tabla_a_desplegar" && document.getElementById("tabla_b_desplegar").style.display == "block") {
    // esconde la tercera tabla (código copiado del segundo enlace)
    desplegar('tabla_b_desplegar','estadoT2', 'estadoTfila')
}
```

El resultado sería algo como esto:

```js
function desplegar(tabla_a_desplegar, estadoT, estadoTfila) {
  
  var tablA = document.getElementById(tabla_a_desplegar);
  var estadOt = document.getElementById(estadoT);
  var fila = document.getElementById(estadoTfila);

  switch (tablA.style.display) {
    case "none":
      tablA.style.display = "block";
      estadOt.innerHTML = "Ocultar";
      fila.innerHTML = "";
      fila.innerHTML = " La fila de id: " + fila.id + ". Contiene: " + fila.innerHTML + " :: " + fila.style.background;
      break;
    default:
      tablA.style.display = "none";
      estadOt.innerHTML = "+Habitacion"
      
      // si la tabla que se oculta es la segunda y la tercera tabla está visible
      if (tablA.id == "tabla_a_desplegar" && document.getElementById("tabla_b_desplegar").style.display == "block") {
        // esconde la tercera tabla
        desplegar('tabla_b_desplegar','estadoT2', 'estadoTfila')
      }
      break;
  }


}
```

```html
<table style="margin-left:27px; margin-right:27px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">Habitacion 1</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">Adulto</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left;margin-top:12px">&nbsp;Ni&ntilde;o</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">
          <a class="registro registrolinea habitacion" id="estadoT" onClick="desplegar('tabla_a_desplegar','estadoT', 'estadoTfila')" style="background: #AEE756; cursor: pointer;">+ Habitacion</a>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">
          <select class="form-control seleccionunoir" id="sel1">

            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>



          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left;margin-top:12px">
          <select class="form-control selecciondosir" id="sel1">

            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>



          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="tabla_a_desplegar" style="margin-left:26px; margin-right:27px; margin-top:-15px; display:none; ">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">Habitacion 2</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px; margin-left:-09px">Adulto</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left;margin-top:12px">&nbsp;Ni&ntilde;o</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">
          <a class="registro registrolinea habitacion" id="estadoT2" onClick="desplegar('tabla_b_desplegar','estadoT2', 'estadoTfila')" style="background: #AEE756; cursor: pointer;">+ Habitacion</a>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px; margin-left:-09px">
          <select class="form-control seleccionunoir" id="sel1">

            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>



          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left;margin-top:12px">
          <select class="form-control selecciondosir" id="sel1">

            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>



          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<table id="tabla_b_desplegar" style="margin-left:26px; margin-right:27px; margin-top:-15px; display:none; ">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">Habitacion 3</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px; margin-left:-09px">Adulto</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left;margin-top:12px">&nbsp;Ni&ntilde;o</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>



      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px;">
          <select class="form-control seleccionunoir" id="sel1">

            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>



          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left;margin-top:12px; ">
          <select class="form-control selecciondosir" id="sel1">

            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>



          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="margin-left:180px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button style="margin: 0 auto" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Buscar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias nuevamente Alvaro que mas decirte que esta completo mi codigo con tu excelente ayuda en pro de seguir aprendiendo muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Realice algunas modificaciones en el `html`, redefiniendo como se llaman los id de los tag y en el `javascript` veras que es necesario recorrer las tablas inferiores para ocultarlas

Analiza el código, veras es bien simple.

```js
function desplegar(nroTabla, estadOt) {

  var tabla = document.getElementById('tabla' + nroTabla);
  //var estadOt = document.getElementById(estadoT);
  //var fila = document.getElementById(estadoTfila);

  switch (tabla.style.display) {
      
    case "none":
      tabla.style.display = "block";
      estadOt.innerHTML = "Ocultar";

      break;
      
    case "block":
      tabla.style.display = "none";
      estadOt.innerHTML = "+Habitacion";
      
      for(i = nroTabla; i<= 3; i++){
          var tablaTemp = document.getElementById('tabla' + i);
          tablaTemp.style.display = "none";
          var estadoTemp = document.getElementById('estadoT' + i);
          estadoTemp.innerHTML = "+Habitacion";
      }
      
      break;
  }


}
```

```html
<table style="margin-left:27px; margin-right:27px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">Habitacion 1</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">Adulto</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left;margin-top:12px">&nbsp;Ni&ntilde;o</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">
          <a class="registro registrolinea habitacion" id="estadoT1" onClick="desplegar(2, this);" style="background: #AEE756; cursor: pointer;">+ Habitacion</a>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">
          <select class="form-control seleccionunoir" id="sel1">

            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>



          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left;margin-top:12px">
          <select class="form-control selecciondosir" id="sel1">

            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>



          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="tabla2" style="margin-left:26px; margin-right:27px; margin-top:-15px; display:none; ">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">Habitacion 2</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px; margin-left:-09px">Adulto</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left;margin-top:12px">&nbsp;Ni&ntilde;o</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">
          <a class="registro registrolinea habitacion" id="estadoT2" onClick="desplegar(3, this);" style="background: #AEE756; cursor: pointer;">+ Habitacion</a>
        </p>
      </td>


      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px; margin-left:-09px">
          <select class="form-control seleccionunoir" id="sel1">

            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>



          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left;margin-top:12px">
          <select class="form-control selecciondosir" id="sel1">

            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>



          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<table id="tabla3" style="margin-left:26px; margin-right:27px; margin-top:-15px; display:none; ">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px">Habitacion 3</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px; margin-left:-09px">Adulto</p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left;margin-top:12px">&nbsp;Ni&ntilde;o</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>



      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left; margin-top:12px;">
          <select class="form-control seleccionunoir" id="sel1">

            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>



          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; text-align:left;margin-top:12px; ">
          <select class="form-control selecciondosir" id="sel1">

            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>



          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="margin-left:180px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button style="margin: 0 auto" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Buscar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```